# Solving PDE using Method of Characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve the following by using the method of characteristics
$$u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=1~,~u|_{x=y}=\frac{x}{2}$$

I have the following characteric equations:

$$\frac{dx}{ds}=u~;\frac{dy}{ds}=1~;\frac{du}{ds}=1$$

from the above I get

$$
x=us+x_{0}
$$ 
$$  
y=s +y_{0}
$$
$$
u=s+u_{0}
$$

I am now thinking I should go with the standard conditions  $$y_0=0$$ and $$u(x,0)=f(x_0)$$

this now gives me:
$$
x=uy+x_o
$$
$$
y=s
$$
$$
u=y+f(x_0)
$$

Im confused because of the $$u$$ term in my equation for $$x$$

Can anyone please help.

Thanks a mil

Comment: You will be more likely to get a good answer if you were to accept those offered on earlier question of yours. It is easy, you just click the tick mark at the top-left of the answer post you found most helpful.

Comment: thanks Sasha  I didnt know about the whole 'accept' thing.  *blush* hope that helps encourage helpers.  ;)

Comment: http://www-solar.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~alan/MT2003/PDE/node8.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to characteristic equations is incorrect, which you can easily check by plugging your current solution back in. The source of the problem is that $u(s)$ is not constant, thus $x^\prime(s) = u(s)$ is **not solved** by $x(s) = u(s) s + x_0$.

It may help to note that $x^{\prime\prime}(s) = u^\prime(s) = 1$. Now that you are back into ODE with constant coefficients, finding solutions should be easy.

Comment: Thanks Sasha.  Do i solve $$\frac{d^2x}{ds^2}=1$$ as: $$\frac{dx}{ds}=s+k$$ and so $$x=\frac{1}{2}s^2+ks+x_0$$ ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You could also use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%28s%29%3D1) to check your results.

Comment: Ok, so the other characteristic equations were right?  So I have $$y=s$$ and $$u=s+f(x_0)$$  and then using what I have above $$x_0=x-\frac{1}{2}y^2-ky$$ I am still confused about what to do about the condition $$u|_x=y=\frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: sorry i tried to edit the comment, but i was too late.  its supposed to say $$u|_{x=y}=\frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: We have $u(s) = s + u_0$, $x(s) = \frac{s^2}{2} + k s + x_0$, and $y(x) = s + y_0$. The boundary conditions $\left. 2 u \right|_{x=y} = x$ means that for $s$, such that $x(s) =y(s)$, $2 u(s) = x(s)$. This leads to a system of equations for the undetermined coefficients.

Comment: do i set up a kind of simultaneous equation thing to solve?  so $$y(s)=x(s)$$ means $$s+y_0=\frac{1}{2}s^2+ks+x_0$$ this is my first equation.  and $$2u(s)=x(s)$$ means $$2s+2u_0=\frac{1}{2}s^2+ks+x_0$$, this is my second equation.  If I take eq2 - eq1 i will get $$s+u_0-y_0=0$$  I dont know if I am on the right track, and if I am, I dont know what to do from here. :(

Comment: sorry, i tried to correct my last statement but i was too late again.   @sasha I would have $$s+2u_0-y_0=0$$

Comment: Solve for $s$ and substitute the solution into the other equation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1513/discussion-between-sarah-jamal-and-sasha)

Comment: its easier to put the math stuff here.  But It says I should move it to chat.  :| ... ok, so I put in the chat that I get $$s=y_0-2u_0$$ so where do I sub this into?  I feel like Im going round in circles.